# Casino roulette Rigid Body

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I’m tying to animate a ball roll in a casino roulette but I having some collision problem.

No matter the physics parameter, the ball don’t really interact with the roulette turning movement.
It rolls down while the roulette is turning and then stops like nothing is interacting with it.

I tried to extrude the roulette surface and played with the physics parameter but nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: Can u show us what u tried? Provide blend file…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select this part here:

[image]

press tab to enter edit mode and choose mesh -> recalculate outside, check animated in rigid body tab, source: final

then select your ball and change shape to mesh, margin to 0

then go to rigid body world and hit "bake"

result:

[image]